# Expandable list view duplicate children

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

The problem is, when I click on any expandable list view header all other headers and their children will turn into the one that been pressed and I don't understand why !?

the idea is that I have an address list. each header is the Address line. the body consists of 3 EditTexts: Address Line, apt, Postal Code. the address lines of the header and the body are the same, when the body address line is changed, it should reflect the address line in the header.

```
public class AddressExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Address> mAddresses;

    public AddressExpandableListAdapter(Context contextIn) {
        mContext = contextIn;
        mAddresses = (MapHelper.getInstance()).getAddressList();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mAddresses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return mAddresses.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int j) {
        return mAddresses.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int j) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addresslist_header, null);
        }

        TextView header = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.addresslist_header_title);
        header.setText(((Address) getGroup(i)).getAddressLine(0));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int j, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        Address data = (Address) getChild(i,j);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addresslist_body, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(view, i);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.setData(data);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        EditText addressLine;
        EditText apt;
        EditText postalCode;
        int position;

        ViewHolder(View viewIn, int i) {

            addressLine = (EditText) viewIn
                    .findViewById(R.id.addresslist_body_addressline);
            apt = (EditText) viewIn
                    .findViewById(R.id.addresslist_body_apt);
            postalCode = (EditText) viewIn
                    .findViewById(R.id.addresslist_body_postalcode);
            position = i;

            setAddressLineWatcher(addressLine);
            setAptWatcher(apt);
            setPostalCodeWatcher(postalCode);
        }

        private void setData(Address data) {
            addressLine.setText(data.getAddressLine(0));
            postalCode.setText(data.getPostalCode());
        }

        private void setAddressLineWatcher(final EditText addressLineIn) {
            TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                boolean changed = false;

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (!changed) {
                        changed = true;
                        addressLineIn.setText(charSequence.toString());
                        updateAddressLine(charSequence.toString(), position);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    changed = false;
                }
            };
            addressLineIn.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }

        private void setAptWatcher(final EditText aptIn) {
            TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                boolean changed = false;

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (!changed) {
                        changed = true;
                        aptIn.setText(charSequence.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    changed = false;
                }
            };

            aptIn.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }

        private void setPostalCodeWatcher(final EditText postalCodeIn) {
            TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                boolean changed = false;

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if (!changed) {
                        changed = true;
                        postalCodeIn.setText(charSequence.toString());
                        updatePostalCode(charSequence.toString(), position);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    changed = false;
                }
            };
            postalCodeIn.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }

    }

    private void updateAddressLine(String charSequence, int position) {
        ((Address) getGroup(position)).setAddressLine(0, charSequence);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void updatePostalCode(String s, int position) {
        ((Address) getGroup(position)).setPostalCode(s);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: did you ever find the answer? i am having same kind of issue ..

Comment: I ended up switching to a recycler view, which fixed the problem. It seems that the problem is with data management.